# Python Compare two lists and check for two unique strings

Tags: python, list, intersection

```
strings = ("name", "last", "middle")
file = ["name","blabla","middle"]
for line in file:
    if any(s in line for s in strings):
        print ("found")
```

I want to compare two lists and get check for the common strings, and **if and only if two or more** strings are same.
The above code works well for **one** but I want it to check for **two** keywords.

Eg: It should **only** `print(found)` if **and only if** 'name' and 'middle' is found. Not only if 'name' is found. It should check for **two** strings.

Comment: Do you have duplicates values in your tuple or list? How do you want to handle strings with different case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can find number of matches using `list comprehension` and then  `len > 2` or not

```
>>> num = 2
>>> l = [i for i in strings if i in file]
>>> if len(l) >= num:
        print('found')
found
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set`s and [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) if you want to check for the common items (and it's not important which ones).

```
if len(set(strings).intersection(file)) >= 2:  # at least 2 common values
    print('found')
```

If you want to look for fixed items you could use the [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) method:

```
strings = ("name", "last", "middle")
file = ["name","blabla","middle"]

check = {'name', 'middle'}  # that's a set containing the items to look for.
if check.issubset(strings) and check.issubset(file):
    print('found')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like one-liners here's my proposition:

```
# If two or more elemnts from listA are present in listB returns TRUE
def two_or_more(listA, listB):
    return sum(map(lambda x : x in listB, listA)) > 1
```